# PHP - How to change reference of a function's pointer parameter from the definition

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 7.4. From the function call, I need to change the reference of a variable passed to it by reference. This is the simplified version of my code to make it clear and more focus on the problem.

```
function f(&$p){
    $p['x'] = [];
    $p = &$p['x'];
    //$p represents $a['x'] here
}
$a = [];
$p = &$a;
f($p);
//$p revert to $a here
$p['y'] = 3;
echo json_encode($a);
```

I expected the function to change the reference of variable `$p` from pointing to `$a` to `$a['x']`. Within the definition scope, it did. But the reference reverted back to `$a` after the call.

So from the above code, instead of this `{"x" : {"y" : 3}}`, I get this `{"x" : {}, "y" : 3}` as the result.

I assume that a function's pointer parameter can only be used to change the value not the reference. But is there any way to do the same for a reference considering that reference is also a type of value?.

Comment: Why would you not just pass $a by reference? what is ```echo json_encode($p);``` ?

Comment: @futureweb to show the example that matches exactly the problem i'm having and passing $a doesn't show it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: What has json_encode got to do with it ? you are passing an array by reference &$p which is copied from an array $a then somehow you expect $a to be equal to $p because you say $p = &a  you are passing $a by ref to $p then passing $p by ref to the function I don't think this will update $a

Comment: No of course the result will be ``` {"x" : {}, "y" : 3}``` you set x to an empty array then json_encode it

Comment: https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/39aa6f0 see

Comment: @futureweb the `json_encode`, `$a`, and `$p`, it's all just to show the example. you can understand the actual problem if you're fully read the question. if i exclude `$a` and just directly do `$p = []` to show the example, `echo json_encode` will display the same result but i can't explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what you needed, your solution is this.

```
function &f(&$p){
    $p['x'] = [];
    $p = &$p['x'];
    return $p;
}
$a = [];
$p = &$a;
$p = &f($p);
$p['y'] = 3;
echo json_encode($a);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. actually i need more straight forward solution which doesn't involve reassigning because the parameter is already a pointer. i take your answer for now but it would be nice if you'd update it with better answer later

Comment: Actually I agree with your concept, because it is logical and as we know references in 'C' have working as you have described.
But PHP blocks the propagation of this assignment $p=&$p['x']; through input parameters between 2 different contexts.
I think in PHP, the maximum what we can do in this case with references, is what I wrote.